# How to define a function that takes natural numbers of a data type and return their sum?

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion, value-constructor

I am still learning how value constructors work. I read a lot about data types and their value constructors. The problem is that I never saw them in practice. For example

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

Now if we want to define a functions that takes two inputs of Nat and returns the product, how would we do that? We have to convert them to Haskell Integrals if we want to use the operator *.
And if we want to implement a mult function that takes two Nat's which should multiply them without converting them to Haskel Integrals, how would that look like?

I really don't get data types|value constructors yet. Can anyone illustrate how to correctly use such value constructors from the data Nat example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat` without converting the arguments to `Integer` first. What is multiplication? It's repeated addition, which you can define recursively:

```
n * 0 == 0
n * m == n + n * (m - 1)
```

Recall that `m - 1` is the value of the `Nat` wrapped by `Succ`; if `m == Succ k`, then `k` represents `m - 1`. With that in mind, you should be able to see how to define `mult`, assuming you have a definition of `add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat` available.

```
mult :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
mult n Zero = ...
mult n (Succ m) = ...
```

`add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat` can be defined similarly, using a definition based on repeated incrementing.

```
-- n + 0 = n
-- n + m = (n + 1) + (m - 1)
def add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add n Zero = ...
add n (Succ m) = ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pattern match on these. For example, we can decrement the number (or return `Zero` in case it was already `Zero`) with:

```
dec :: Nat -> Nat
dec Zero = Zero
dec (Succ n) = n
```

Here the patterns are thus `Zero`, which matches the `Zero` value, and `Succ n`, which will thus unify `n` with the value wrapped in the `Succ` data constructor.

If you want to sum up two `Nat`s, you thus define a function `add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat`. You first might want to try all possible cases for the data constructors of the two values, and perhaps later look to improve your code by generalizing the clauses.

Comment: The problem is that I want to return a natural number and I am not show how to call a function that returns a number and not the value constructor itselt. How would the function look like if I would like to enter 2 and get back an integral? I do not see the usefullness,,

Comment: You call a function `f` with parameter `x` as `f x`.

Comment: I know that. I think I have a false understanding of how it works. I have to read further